# what is boiler-plate code? why should it be avoided?

Tags: refactoring, boilerplate

What is boiler-plate code, and why it is called like that?
Example for android:

```
onCreate(Bundle saveInstance){
    setcontentView(R.layout.m);

    findViewById(R.id.f1);
    findViewById(R.id.f2);
    findViewById(R.id.f3);
    findViewById(R.id.f4);
}
```

What other examples are there? Why should we avoid boiler-plate code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boilerplate code is repetitious code that needs to be included in many places. The origins are well explained by the [wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code):

> Interestingly, the term arose from the newspaper business. Columns and other pieces that were syndicated were sent out to subscribing newspapers in the form of a mat (i.e. a matrix). Once received, boiling lead was poured into this mat to create the plate used to print the piece, hence the name boilerplate. As the article printed on a boilerplate could not be altered, the term came to be used by attorneys to refer to the portions of a contract which did not change through repeated uses in different applications, and finally to language in general which did not change in any document that was used repeatedly for different occasions.

There are several problems with boilerplate code:

1. It's error prone. Your example may be straight-forward, but not all boilerplate instances are. In cases where the code includes a bit more logic to it there's more room to make mistakes (=bugs). Especially if these blocks just get copy-pasted from place to place, but require some alterations to work.
2. Moreover - if you ever have to change this logic, it's much harder to do, as you need to go over several places to do it.
3. It takes up screen realestate and attention. More code to read means there's more things you need to process when trying to understand a piece of code you're reading. Boilerplate code just adds another distraction.
4. It takes up actual space in the final (usually compiled) product. What would you rather deliver? A 1MB JAR file or a 10MB one?